# Something Strange happend in lua regexp,What's wrong with my script?

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

Lua's regexp isn't compatible with Posix RegExp. For example, `%d` means `\d` which represents Number:0 to 9. And '%' is for escaping.

I want to match something like `"180*180,512*512"` which describe image size sequencies.  In Posix mode,This regexp does work for me: `^(\d+\*\d+)(,\d+\*\d+)*$`, And I changed this to Lua regexp mode: `^(%d+%*%d+)(,%d+%*%d+)*$`, but it doesn't work. Here is my code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/lua

source = '96*96,180*180';
format = "^(%d+%*%d+)(,%d+%*%d+)*$";


if (not string.find(source, format)) then
    print 'wrong!'
else
    print 'ok!'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua *does not* have regex. It has its own patterns, as [described in PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).

For your particular case, you can simple replace the regex:

```
^(\d+\*\d+)(,\d+\*\d+)*$
```

to the following pattern:

```
^(%d+%*%d+)(,%d+%*%d+)$
```

Note that I removed the `*` after your second match-group, because Lua does not support it. You'll have to resort to using `gmatch` for capturing multiple groups:

```
local tMatches = {}
for sSize in str:gmatch "(%d+%*%d+)" do
    table.insert( tMatches, sSize )
end
```

Comment: Thx, you figured out my problem.

Comment: @ruibin If the post helped, you can select it as the answer :)

Comment: Lua supports using `*`

Comment: @hjpotter92 My bad, I did not realize at first you meant using `*` on capture groups. Yes, you are right =D